# PyCharm Run Issues Django With External Virtual Environment

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm 2016.3.2 on Windows 10. I have a Django project using an separate virtual environment( ie. virtual environment is in totally separate folder to the project). I am using a Postgres server which is working fine and can be seen by Pycharm and can test connect. The problem I have is when I go to Run it in Pycharm the server is not starting. I get the following in the Run window:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Pyprojects\VirtualEnvs\venv2\Scripts\python.exe C:/Pyprojects/MyProject/manage.py runserver 8000

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I can attest to this all actually working outside Pycharm. I can use 'runserver' from my virtual environment using Windows command prompt. I can then get into my django site once I've started it that way with no problems.

Can anyone shed some light on how to make this work with Pycharm? I just purchased Pycharm professional and hopefully this will have some kind of easy fix.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Marco

Comment: Go to settings and see what is the project interpreter

Comment: Hi subha. I've set that in there already to what I believe should be correct: Python 3.6.0 virtualenv at C:\Pyprojects\VirtualEnvs\venv2: Python 3.6.0

Comment: and still not running? From the play like green button? @Marco

Comment: Ok I found the solution with this issue..>Seems like a Windows related bug talked about here to do with setting an Environmental variable in the Run configurations of Pycharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17069#comment=27-1804561&u=1482137902791     Basically you need to add an environmental variable that looks like this "=C:=c:\"  Another one of those obscure bugs I seem to run into...